# Локальная таблица рекордов

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, linq

Хочу реализовать таблицу рекордов формата "*имя - рекорд*" в игре, используя **json**. А сортировать при помощи **LINQ**. Но не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

Идея такая:

1. В главном меню перед началом игры игроку нужно ввести имя (3 символа) - это имя сохраняется. (Думаю использовать InputField и из него извлечь введённое имя)
2. В ходе игры сохраняется рекорд этого игрока, или перезаписывается старый, если рекорд был побит.
3. Ну и в главном меню также будет кнопка перехода на сцену, где будут все игроки с их рекордами отображаться отсортированные при помощи LINQ.

Вот такой код у меня сейчас имеется:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    class SaveData
    {
        public int record;
        public string playerName;
    }

    public void SaveRecord()
    {
        SaveData data = new SaveData
        {
            record = _highScore,
            playerName = PLAYER_NAME
        };

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);

        File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savefile.json", json);
    }

    public void LoadRecord()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/savefile.json";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            SaveData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveData>(json);

            _highScore = data.record;
            PLAYER_NAME = data.playerName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Идея неплохая, начинайте её реализовывать!

Comment: @KOTlK Хотя бы описать как это возможно реализовать, я же ясно написал что **не** понимаю.

Comment: использовать InputField и из него извлечь введённое имя, в ходе игры сохранять рекорд, сделать кнопку в главном меню, нажатие на которую будет загружать сцену с рекордами. Ты сам описал то, что тебе нужно делать. Что КОНКРЕТНО ты не понимаешь?

Comment: что такое `JsonUtility`? Используйте `System.Text.Json`

Comment: и вы работаете с json так, будто у вас таблица рекордов должна состоять только из 1го игрока

Comment: @iKuzmichov штатный Unity сериализатор (кстати глючный и неполноценный), System.Text.Json в Unity отсутствует, но вроде из NuGet можно поставить его.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, буду знать

Comment: @KOTlK КОНКРЕТНО, как грамотно сохранить необходимые мне данные, как их грамотно загрузить, и изобразить в таблице на сцене.

Comment: Делай как можешь. Твой вариант пойдет, только ты сохраняешь один рекорд, а ты хочешь сохранять список. При сохранении, загружай уже имеющийся список рекордов, ищи в нем нужное имя и обновляй рекорд. Для выведения рекордов на экран, просто загружай этот список и сортируй его как хочешь. Если дефолтный юнитивский сериализатор с чем-от не справляется, есть [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Install-official-via-UPM), который поддерживается юнити

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Как написать лидерборд**

---

**Result.cs**

Модель единицы результата с конструктором и переопределением `ToString` для удобства дебага

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace LiderboardSystem
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct Result
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Score;
        public long DateLong; // DateTime не сериализуется, utc формат

        public Result (string name, int score, DateTime date)
        {
            Name = name;
            Score = score;
            DateLong = date.ToFileTimeUtc();
        }

        public Result (string name, int score) : this(name, score, DateTime.Now)
        {
        }

        public DateTime Date => DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(DateLong);

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            var dateStr = Date.ToString("G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Name, Score, dateStr);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Table.cs**

Таблица это модель для сохранения в `json` содержащая только коллекцию результатов и несколько методов для работы с этими результатами.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace LiderboardSystem
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Table
    {
        [SerializeField] private List<Result> _results;

        public Table ()
        {
            _results = new List<Result>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Result> Results => Results;

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            int lenght = _results.Count;
            int numberCount = (int)Mathf.Floor(Mathf.Log10(lenght));
            string indexFormat = "D"+numberCount;
            var rows = _results.Select((r, i) => string.Format("{0} {1}", i.ToString(indexFormat), r.ToString()));
            return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rows);
        }

        public Result AddResult (string name, int score)
        {
            var newResult = new Result(name, score);
            _results.Add(newResult);
            Sort();
            return newResult;
        }

        public void Crop (int lenght)
        {
            if (_results.Count > lenght)
                _results.RemoveRange(lenght, _results.Count-lenght);
        }

        public void Clean ()
        {
            _results.Clear();
        }

        private void Sort ()
        {
            _results.Sort((x, y) => y.Score.CompareTo(x.Score));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Liderboard.cs**

Обертка для таблицы занимающийся ее сохранением при модификации и загрузкой в виде `ScriptableObject`, что делает доступ к доске простым для любого объекта на сцене которые будет вносить новые результаты или отображать имеющиеся

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace LiderboardSystem
{
    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Liderboard", menuName = "Liderboard")]
    public class Liderboard : ScriptableObject
    {
        private const string Key = "Liderboard";
        [SerializeField] private int _capacity = 10;
        private Table _table;

        public IEnumerable<Result> Results => _table.Results;

        // инициировать при старте игры в точке входа
        public void Initialize ()
        {
            Load();
        }

        public Result AddResult (string name, int score)
        {
            var result = _table.AddResult(name, score);
            _table.Crop(_capacity);
            Save();
            return result;
        }

        public void Clean ()
        {
            _table.Clean();
            Save();
        }

        private void Load ()
        {
            string json = PlayerPrefs.GetString(Key);
            Debug.Log(json);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                _table = new Table();
            else
                _table = JsonUtility.FromJson<Table>(json);
        }

        private void Save ()
        {
            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(_table);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(Key, json);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
}
```