# Не могу разобраться в serializable

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, save

Есть static массив из объектов другого класса , на 4 элемента , у каждого объекта есть ID
Сохраняю игру в Json файл , в том числе сохраняю и массив, то есть в объект класса sv , где есть поле куда я буду сохранять массив я сохраняю static массив.

Массив называется Party в него я засовываю объекты персонажей.

(при выходе из игры)
sv.Party = Party

(При запуске в awake)
Party=sv.Party

В массивах проставил тэг [Serializable]

Но при проверке сохраняется только последний элемент причём во все 4 ячейки.

То есть если у меня есть отряд из персонажей с ID 1 ,2 ,8 ,10
То во все 4 ячейки массива сохраняется , а в дальнейшем и загружается [10,10,10,10]

Объект персонажа имеет такие поля (sting name, string desc, int ID , int HP, in Damage)

Я так же ранее сохранял очень много других полей , но они были не объектами,а просто значимыми переменными ,то есть int , float, bool и проблем нету всё работает как нужно , а вот с объектами класса так уже не получается, помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: В момент сохранения]
[image: После Загрузки]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код загрузки, сохранения, объекта сохранения/загрузки  покажи. куда проще и яснее писанины.

Comment: @Yaroslav, вы верно указали на необходимость кода и о том, что ознакомление с ним даст куда больше информации, но и про уважительный тон забывать не стоит

Comment: Вместо того что-бы требовать какие-либо тона лучше бы взглянул по сторонам, как люди вопросы задают, есть даже соответствующая статья в справке [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Если вопрос не теоретический, писанина ваще никого тут не интересует от слова совсем, она только комментарий а не объект обсуждения.

Comment: Статики не должно быть. Ознакомся с тем как делать сохранение на примере таблицы лидербордов [в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1400218/%d0%9b%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2/1400513#1400513).