# Локальная таблица рекордов json

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Для таблицы рекордов пытаюсь реализовать сохранение списка игроков и их рекордов в json.

Проблема в том, что постоянно перезаписывается первая структура, которая создаётся, а в список добавляются пустые структуры со значениями имя игрока null а рекорд 0.
Например, сессию отыграл игрок Max и его рекорд 200 очков. В json сохраняется структура с его данными.
После начинает сессию игрок Aaa и его рекорд 300 очков. В json в список добавляется новый игрок с пустыми данными. А в данные игрока Max вписываются данные игрока Aaa.

Код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[System.Serializable]
public struct SaveData
{
    [JsonProperty("HighScore")]
    public int Record { get; }

    [JsonProperty("PlayerName")]
    public string PlayerName { get; }

    public SaveData(int score, string name)
    {
        PlayerName = name;
        Record = score;
    }
}



public class Results
{
    public List<SaveData> _playersResults;
    const string filepath = @"C:\Games\ApplePicker\save.json";

    public Results()
    {
        _playersResults = new();
    }

    public void SaveRecord(string name, int score)
    {
        var newRecord = new SaveData(score, name);

        if (_playersResults.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var player in _playersResults)
            {
                if (newRecord.PlayerName == player.PlayerName && newRecord.Record > player.Record)
                {
                    _playersResults.Remove(player);
                    _playersResults.Add(newRecord);
                }
            }
            _playersResults.Add(newRecord);
        }
        else
        {
            _playersResults.Add(newRecord);
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_playersResults);

        File.WriteAllText(filepath, json);
    }

    public void LoadRecord()
    {
        foreach (var player in _playersResults)
        {
            if (player.PlayerName == GameManager.PLAYER_NAME)
            {
                GameManager.HIGHSCORE = player.Record;
            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadAllRecords()
    {
        if (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SaveData>>(json);
            _playersResults.AddRange(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопроизвел ваш код, в файл не записываю, смотрю по точке останова на  ```string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_playersResults);``` все окей. Посмотрите что у вас там. И прикрепите как вы вызываете методы

Comment: Дубликат [Как написать лидерборд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1400218/%d0%9b%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2/1400513#1400513)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `SaveData` сделать классом, и убрать путаницу в логике, то получится вот так

```
public class SaveData
{
    public int HighScore { get; }
    public string PlayerName { get; }

    public SaveData(int highScore, string playerName)
    {
        PlayerName = playerName;
        Record = highScore;
    }
}

public class Results
{
    private List<SaveData> _playersResults; // было public, зачем?
    const string filepath = @"C:\Games\ApplePicker\save.json";

    public Results()
    {
        _playersResults = new();
    }

    public void SaveRecord(string name, int score)
    {
        var newRecord = new SaveData(score, name);
        var oldRecord = _playersResults.Find(x => x.PlayerName == name); // есть же Find у списка, пользуйтесь!
        if (oldRecord == null || oldRecord.HighScore < newRecord.HighScore)
        {
            if (oldRecord != null)
                _playersResults.Remove(oldRecord);
            _playersResults.Add(newRecord);
        
            try // всегда при работе с IO обрабатывайте исключения
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_playersResults);
                File.WriteAllText(filepath, json);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadRecord()
    {
        var player = _playersResults.Find(x => x.PlayerName == GameManager.PLAYER_NAME);
        if (player != null)
            GameManager.HIGHSCORE = player.HighScore;
    }

    public void LoadAllRecords()
    {
        try
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
            _playersResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SaveData>>(json); // не нужно AddRange
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // лучше погасить исключение, потому что File.Exists не даст гарантии, что ошибки чтения не будет
        {
            Debug.Log(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сам уже разобрался. 
Скорее всего newtonsoft.json не мог подобрать конструктор для структуры.
Лист был паблик т.к. сериализуются же только публичные объекты нет?

А вот за Find спасибо огромное! Он не слишком расточителен?

Comment: @renmaks если ответ помог, вы можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа. А сериализуются только публичные члены класса, который подлежит сериализации, где при этом хранится сам список - без разницы.

Comment: @renmaks Find прекрасно оптимизирован, я бы даже сказал, лучше чем foreach для списка.

Comment: @renmaks обновил ответ, посмотрите на SaveData, он теперь вообще без атрибутов, и все должно работать, Json сериализатор должен сам схватить правильно аргументы конструктора, так как они называются так же как свойства.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге сам решил:

1. Добавил аттрибут [JsonConstructor].
2. В методе SaveRecord заменил цикл foreach на for.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[System.Serializable]
public struct SaveData
{
    [JsonProperty("HighScore")]
    public int Record { get; }

    [JsonProperty("PlayerName")]
    public string PlayerName { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public SaveData([JsonProperty("HighScore")] int score, [JsonProperty("PlayerName")] string name)
    {
        PlayerName = name;
        Record = score;
    }
}



public class Results
{
    public List<SaveData> _playersResults;
    const string filepath = @"C:\Games\ApplePicker\save.json";

    private bool _isRewrite;
    private bool _isRecordChange;

    public Results()
    {
        _playersResults = new();
    }

    public void SaveRecord(string name, int score)
    {
        var newRecord = new SaveData(score, name);

        _isRewrite = false;
        if (_playersResults.Count != 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < _playersResults.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (newRecord.PlayerName == _playersResults[i].PlayerName && newRecord.Record > _playersResults[i].Record)
                    {
                        _playersResults.Remove(_playersResults[i]);
                        _playersResults.Add(newRecord);
                        _isRewrite = true;
                    }
                }
            if (_isRewrite == false)
            {
                _playersResults.Add(newRecord);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _playersResults.Add(newRecord);
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_playersResults);

        File.WriteAllText(filepath, json);
    }

    public void LoadRecord()
    {
        _isRecordChange = false;
            foreach (var player in _playersResults)
            {
                if (player.PlayerName == GameManager.PLAYER_NAME)
                {
                    GameManager.HIGHSCORE = player.Record;
                    _isRecordChange = true;
                }
            }
        if (_isRecordChange != true)
        {
            GameManager.HIGHSCORE = 0;
        }
    }

    public void LoadAllRecords()
    {
        if (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SaveData>>(json);
            _playersResults = new List<SaveData>(data);
        }
    }
}
```