# Как заменить использование Singleton?

Tags: unity3d

Всем мирного неба!
Я уже довольно таки давно пишу свою первую игру. Это не платформер и не минимальная аркадная стрелялка, в нём много разного функционала, которого не найдёшь в обучающих уроках по Unity. Честно  говоря самому делать такой проект и особенно первопроходцу очень сложно. Я уже несколько раз выгорал и бросал это дело то на неделю то на 3, было так что и на несколько месяцев. Каждый раз возвращаясь я смотрю на свой код с ужасом. Каждый раз хочется всё удалить и переписать. И я уже это делал и скажу что мой код стал лучше прежнего но всё же такой же отвратительный в плане планирования и проектирования. Сейчас у меня есть много проблем в коде и многие я понимаю, понимаю и закрываю глаза(работает значит не лезу). Сделал выводи с этого проекта и буду готов к следующему лучше. Но по поводу Singleton-а у меня осталось много вопросов. Много кто из сеньйоров-разработчиков хейтит и плюётся на этот паттерн. Прошу кидаться в меня камнями только с подробными разъяснениями и желательно с примерами. Очень прошу доступно пояснить неопытному масленку как надо правильно его применять и где необходимо заменить.

И так! Скажу честно и не буду лукавить у меня много Singleton-а, практически везде.
Вот например, загружается сцена и скрип которой отвечает за отображение данных в UI подтягивает все данные для отображения.

```
private void FirstInitValues()
{
    textDepth.text = Player.Instance.Depth.ToString();
    textRegCoin.text = Player.Instance.CoinRegular.ToString();
    textDonatCoin.text = Player.Instance.CoinDonat.ToString();
    imgHealth.fillAmount = Health.Instance.Value / 100;
    imgShield.fillAmount = Shield.Instance.Value / 100;
    imgFuel.fillAmount = Fuel.Instance.Value / 100;
    textInventory.text = Inventory.Instanse.CurrentCapacity.ToString() + " / " +
        Inventory.Instanse.MaxCapacity.ToString();
    textStorage.text = Storage.Instanse.CurrentCapacity.ToString() + " / " +
        Storage.Instanse.MaxCapacity.ToString();
}
```

Также в процессе игры когда идёт расход топлива или идёт какой-то урон то игроку то на это у меня есть события и это скажу честно ппц как круто, подписался и делаешь что там нужно. С этим у меня более менее(наверное). Но у меня много где в коде вызывается сингл скрипта какого то объекта для его использования, задачи могут быть разные: вызвать функцию объекта, взять значения, проверить что то. И дело в том что я для нужд вызвал один раз в скрипте и всё, и мне так легче было бы, вызвал там где надо через сингл и пошёл дальше не парясь. Но я всё же хочу разобраться с этим что бы бить лучше. Я не понимаю как мне вызвать по другому. Я понимаю что можно через инспектор и SerializeField добавить этот объект и делать с ним что мне нужно, но я использую этот объект там раз или два. И таких микро использований у меня много. Прошу помочь и прояснить это мне.

Comment: Начни изучать один из принципов SOLID, последний - Dependency Inversion (DI), и в частности фреймворк Zenject Unity, они могут полностью заменить использование Sington-ов и улучшить вашу архитектуру кода

Comment: `... но я использую этот объект там раз или два` Если ты используешь раз или два объект, то это уже зависимость и ее нужно передавать явно через конструктор или, в случае с монобехами, через сериализуемое поле или через метод инициализации. В твоем случае, если ты захочешь сделать хп не только персонажу, но и кому-то другому, то тебе придется делать отдельный скрипт, а не переиспользовать уже имеющийся Health.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Причина хейта проста, `Singleton` выглядит как палочка выручалочка и ответ на любой вопрос при любой трудности, потому что это `static`. Проблема не в самом паттерне а в `static` и всем что с ним связано!

Обратная сторона `static` в том что если им пользуешься, у тебя все и везде по поводу и без становиться статическим. Синьер уровень прохаванный и способен бить себя по рукам, в результате чего будет бить и всех остальных. Это касается как не странно и джуниор уровня, уже на нем ты должен понимать что такое архитектура. Есть скажем самоуверенные джуниоры называющие себя синьерами в интернетах , лишь бы кого похейтить и поплевать.

Вопрос почему люди так много пользуется статикой в том, что они не умеют выстраивать архитектуру и не видят другого выхода. Можно конечно использовать `Zenject`, но тогда ты не научишься этому навыку. Это умение абстрактно думать и писать классы дробя по принципу `Single responsibility` и строить из этого дерево зависимостей, что бы все соответствовало принципу `Dependency inversion`. `SOLID` принципы это основа основ, начинаем с `Sr`, продолжаем `Di`, подключаем `Interface segregation` и код уже конфетка, ни один синьер не плюнет.

Нет универсального способа избежать `Singleton`, в этом и трудность. К тому-же различные инструменты увеличивают количество способов, например `ScriptableObject` в `Unity`. Таким образом можно написать скажем [лидерборд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1400513/352119) и ссылку на этот `so` будет только у скрипта который записывает в конце сессии и у панельки отображающей результаты в меню, плюс нет привязанности к конкретной сцене, таких связей может быть не 2, а 10-20 и все-равно удобно. Но полное отсутствии статики это конечно влажная мечта помешенного программиста, есть ограниченное количество вещей когда количество мест может быть невероятно велико и пробрасывать к каждой зависимости просто не целесообразно, как например игровая статистика, которая может собирать данные по каждому чиху везде и по всюду, моб `m` убит, предмет `i` подобран/получен/выкинут/использован, золото `g` подобрано/получено/потрачено, вход в/выход из локация `l` и.д. И все это используется кем-то еще, например системой миссий/квестов/событий.

`Sr` и `Di` соответственно тоже нужно использовать с умом, иначе можно упароться до крайности как в видео [Соер FizzBazz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWmmfDvcYO0&t=1286s), где из 2 притопа, 3 прихлопа вышло 7 сущьностей но все строго по `SOLID`. В примере с лидербордом я например не стал выделять процесс сохранения в отдельную ответственность, зацементировав её на локальном `PlayerPrefs`, что для казуалки на Unity обыденность, только время терять.

Comment: Спасибо!  Нужно будет изучить и потренироваться на паре или тройке тестовых проектов что бы пришло хоть какое-то начальное понимание этой годноты.